# Use of std::find_if with flexible arrays

Tags: c++

Let's say that I have the following two structures, where `struct sB` has a flexible array:

```
struct sA
{
  double valueA;
  double valueB;
};

struct sB
{
  double c;
  size_t arrayMembers;
  sA aM[];
};
```

I want to iterate over `aM` and find the first element with `valueA > c and valueB > c`. I want to do it using `std::find_if()`.

I tried to use `std::begin()` and `std::end()`:

```
auto primeElement = std::find_if(std::begin(sBInstance.aM), std::end(sBInstance.aM),
      [&](const sB v){return (v.valueA > c && v.valueB > c)});
```

However, it doesn't compile with a compiler error (among other related errors):

> 'std::begin' : no matching overloaded function found

I think that flexible arrays are more C than C++, and C++ iterators maybe are not particularly suited to them, but is there a way I can use `std::find_if()` on a flexible array? If there is more than one way, which one is the most straightforward?

Comment: Standard C++ does support flexible arrays.  You can use a `std::vector`

Comment: We've determined, this morning (UTC-0500), that [there is no such thing as a flexible array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75532794/). And, it's now later in the day, there's still no such thing as a "flexible array" in C++. And that's why none of the C++ library functions and algorithms have any idea what to do with such an exotic creature. How could `std::end(sBInstance.aM)` possibly know how many values are in this `aM`. The only thing the suffering `std::end()` function has is a pointer, with no clue as to how many values are being pointed to.

Comment: Pointers-as-iterators (`std::find_if(sBInstance.aM, sBInstance.aM + sB.arrayMembers, <lambda>)`) not working for some reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard C++ does not support flexible array members.  That is a C feature that is not part of C++.  If you need an object with a variable-length array as a member, use `std::vector` instead.

---

If your compiler supports flexible array members as an extension, you'll need to treat them more like pointers to dynamically-allocated arrays rather than statically-sized C arrays.  Since their size is not known at compile time, `std::end()` cannot statically compute an appropriate offset.  Instead, you'll need to add `arrayMembers` as an offset to the `aM` member pointing to the first element of the array:

```
auto primeElement = std::find_if(
    sBInstance->aM,
    sBInstance->aM + sBInstance->arrayMembers,
    [&](const sA& v){ return v.valueA > c && v.valueB > c; }
);
```

This works because pointers are a type of iterator, so pointers to the beginning of an array and to one-past-the-end of an array are a valid iterator range to iterate over that array.

Comment: Thanks Miles, I would like to have a solution without pointer arithmetics, byt it seems clear that this cannot be the case

Comment: @km1234 Indeed, pointer arithmetic is the only way to find the end of an array that the compiler doesn't know the size of.  Even things like `std::vector` and `std::string` use pointer arithmetic to track their end; they just hide it away in their internal implementation.